# Use Proxy in C# Portable Class Library (Microsoft.Net.Http)

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest, webproxy

I would like to know how to use a Proxy in a HttpWebRequest within a Portable Class Library (PCL).

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21979164/webproxy-on-portable-class-library) that the IWebProxy interface did not have any implementation within the Microsoft.Net.Http library.

I need my HttpWebRequest to use a WebProxy. Any idea on how to do this in a PCL?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can use your own implementation of `IWebProxy` (I haven't tested it on WinRT, but it works on the desktop with `HttpClient`)

```
class MyProxy : IWebProxy
{
    private readonly Uri _proxyUri;
    public MyProxy(Uri proxyUri)
    {
        _proxyUri = proxyUri;
    }

    public ICredentials Credentials { get; set; }
    public Uri GetProxy(Uri destination)
    {
        return _proxyUri;
    }
    public bool IsBypassed(Uri destination)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient seems to exist in PCL, which can be used like this: [Using a proxy with .NET 4.5 HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16526689/using-a-proxy-with-net-4-5-httpclient) (You may find an answer in this if i see it correctly)

Comment: The problem is not HttpClient, but the fact that the WebProxy class doesn't exist in WinRT